# Join subquery with multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've to perform a join with a table named Accounts and that looks like:

[image]

I want to get the Account number for the best match possible, independently of the Type.

I mean, if I have the company "BP" I only want the account values 33 and 44 (rows with the IDs 2 and 4), otherwise, I should get the rows 1 and 3 where the company is null.

I tried without success the join bellow with the COALESCE function. If I have a company, I always get the 2 rows for the company and another 2 rows where the company is null.

```
inner join accounts
            on accounts.id in
                (select COALESCE(accountsWithComp.id,accountsWithoutComp.id) 
                    from accounts

                    left join (
                            select id
                            from accounts

                            where accounts.portfolio=position.portfolio
                            and accounts.counterparty=position.cp
                            ) accountsWithComp
                            on accountsWithComp.id = accounts.id
    
                    left join (
                            select id
                            from accounts

                            where accounts.portfolio=position.portfolio
                            and accounts.counterparty is null
                            ) accountsWithoutComp
                            on accountsWithoutComp.id = accounts.id
            )
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're almost there.

The logic you want is "only get a row from accounts with a null company if we couldn't find a row with a matching company.

So you want to left join on accounts twice, and have the second left join "care about" the result of the first left join.

Here's a simplified example:

```
create table t(i int);
create table u(i int, c char null, d char);

insert t values (1), (2);
insert u values (1, 'c', 'a'), (2, null, 'b');

select      t.i,
            coalesce(u1.d, u2.d)
from        t
            -- preferably get a row with a value for c
left join   u  u1 on u1.i = t.i 
                     and u1.c = 'c'
            -- only get a row without a value for c if we didn't get a row in u1
left join   u  u2 on u1.c is null 
                     and u2.i = t.i 
                     and u2.c is null
```

In your case that means changing this:

```
left join (
        select id
        from accounts

        where accounts.portfolio=position.portfolio
        and accounts.counterparty is null
        ) accountsWithoutComp
        on accountsWithoutComp.id = accounts.id
```

to this...

```
left join (
        select id
        from accounts

        where accounts.portfolio=position.portfolio
        and accounts.counterparty is null
        ) accountsWithoutComp
        on accountsWithoutComp.id = accounts.id
           and accoutnsWithComp.id is null -- additional condition added here
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `left join` the first match, then `left join` the second match if the first didn't get a result.

The subqueries seem completely pointless.

```sql
select ISNULL(a1.id, a2.id) 
....
....
left join accounts a1 on a1.portfolio = position.portfolio
                    and a1.counterparty = position.cp
    
left join accounts a2 on a2.portfolio = position.portfolio
                     and a2.counterparty is null
                     and a1.id is null  -- add this condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, might get you there.  I am assuming counterparty in your sql is actually the company column in accounts.

FROM Position  t
LEFT JOIN Accounts a on t.Portfolio = a.Portfolio and (t.counterparty = a.Company or a.Company is null and t.counterparty Not in (Select Company From Accounts b where b.Company = t.counterparty and b.Portfolio = t.Portfolio ))